# Перемещение курсора мыши от кнопки Пуск Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi

Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня при загрузке raspbian мышка появляется сначала в центре монитора, а потом отскакивает на кнопку "Пуск" (не знаю как она в линухе называется)

А мне нужно ее спрятать в правый нижний угол, чтобы курсор видно не было

Как сделать это через bash нашел xdotool и xautomation
Но при установке оба пакета мне ответили:
Unable to locate package

и https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82264/xdotool-for-raspbian-stretch не помогло

попробовал через скрипт на питоне с помощью pyautogui
норм, убегает (при запуске и Thonny IDE)
а при запуске из консоли пишет
File....., line 8, in 
import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

в системе основным стоит python 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Запусти программу unclutter - курсор будет прятаться через какое-то время и появляться только при движении мыши.